# Android location geocoder

Tags: android

У меня есть асинк таск который по заданным координатам начали и конца получает от гугла маршрут и строит маршрут на карте. Мне необходимо сделать фильтр для пользователя по совпадению маршрута. Маршрут я получаю в виде массива точек ArrayList<LatLng>. Каким образом это реализовать правильно? Допустим, как я вижу это. Например, есть 500 пользователей, и придется в цикле для каждого находить маршрут по ихним координатам потом проверять если маршрут входит или пересекается с данным маршрутом и так придется делать для 500 штук, а это неудобно в плане трафика и в плане скорости работы, так как мобильный интернет в Украине не славится скоростью. Можно конечно же этот массив точек получить один раз и отправить на сервер, но опять же, какая разница с гугла получать этот массив или со своего сервера, так что трафик от этого не уменьшится. Каким образом тут поступить? Спасибо. 
P.S. для минусующих. Если вы достигли хорошего или даже высокого уровня программирования, и считаете, что мои вопросы тупые, то извольте пройти мимо. Все люди разные и у них разные способности, разный уровень знаний и тем более разный уровень опыта. А форум я так понимаю для всех.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Максимально вынесите все на свой сервер. (Приложение отдает на сервер координаты. Сервер решает все поблемы с гуглом. Приложение никак не связано с гуглом, а лишь получает конкретный ответ от вашего сервера.)
2. Ответ от сервера должен содержать массив координат и вашу служебную инфу, совпадает/пересекается/частично совпадает с другими маршрутами - и так далее.
3. На сервере при получении координат от приложения - общаемся с гуглом - и получаем маршрут. (я бы попытался сделать еще 1 запрос на гугл - получить выборку из основных точек, а не весь маршрут, чтобы потом удобнее организовать поиск.)
4. Вот впринципе и все.

Comment: спасибо. понял. осталось только на пхп написать все это.

Comment: Незачто. Но ваш вопрос очень сложен для восприятия. Попытайтесь в следуйщий раз следовать http://blog.hashcode.ru/2011/01/blog-post_8123.html

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле надо делать через сервер: 
во-первых, таким образом вы в любом случае уменьшите трафик, в сравнении с клиентской реализацией.

А во-вторых, на сервере можно использовать gzip, и тогда текстовые данные могут сжиматься до 80%, что существенно лучше.